# Twitter login is disabled and greyed out when the activity is initialized

Tags: android, facebook, twitter

In my LoginActivity, user can login either using Facebook and Twitter. The Facebook login button is working fine. However, the Twitter login button is always greyed out and disabled, as below:

[Twitter login button greyed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Umktg.png)

I found one way to enable the button, which is to rotate the screen to landscape. It is then enabled and when I rotate the screen back to portrait it keeps being enabled. It doesn't make sense to tell the user to rotate the screen to enable the button.

I am new to android. Please help. Thanks a lot.

Here is my manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.foodie">

<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
     location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality.
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:name=".Facebook"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges=
            "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="Foodie"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" />

    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/.
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="####" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_map" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity android:name=".CategoryActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".LocationActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".TypeActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".HourActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".PriceActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".OptionsActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".PhotoActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>

    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>

    <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider####"
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
        android:exported="true" />
</application>
```

And here is my code for LoginActivity.

```
package com.example.foodie;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.AccessTokenTracker;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.Profile;
import com.facebook.ProfileTracker;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Result;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Twitter;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthToken;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterCore;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterException;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterSession;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterLoginButton;

import static com.example.foodie.R.id.etPassword;
import static com.example.foodie.R.id.etUsername;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText UsernameEt, PasswordEt;
    String str_username, str_password, type;
    Button bLogin;
    CallbackManager callbackManager;
    AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker;
    ProfileTracker profileTracker;
    String name;
    TwitterLoginButton twitterLoginButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        Twitter.initialize(this);
        twitterLoginButton = (TwitterLoginButton) findViewById(R.id.tlogin_button);
        twitterLoginButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
                TwitterSession session = TwitterCore.getInstance().getSessionManager().getActiveSession();
                TwitterAuthToken authToken = session.getAuthToken();
                String token = authToken.token;
                String secret = authToken.secret;
                String msg = "@" + session.getUserName() + " logged in! (#" + session.getUserId() + ")";
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
            }
        });

        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldToken, AccessToken newToken) {

            }
        };
        profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile newProfile) {
                displayWelcomeMessage(newProfile);
            }
        };
        accessTokenTracker.startTracking();
        profileTracker.startTracking();

        FacebookCallback<LoginResult> callback= new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
                if(Profile.getCurrentProfile() == null){
                    profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
                        @Override
                        protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile newProfile) {
                            displayWelcomeMessage(newProfile);
                            name = newProfile.getName();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("name", name);
                            intent.putExtra("photo", photo);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    };
                }
                else {
                    Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                    displayWelcomeMessage(profile);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    name = profile.getName();
                    intent.putExtra("name", name);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // App code
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                // App code
            }
        };

        loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, callback);

        UsernameEt = (EditText) findViewById(etUsername);
        PasswordEt = (EditText) findViewById(etPassword);
        bLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogin);
        bLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                login();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        twitterLoginButton.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    private void displayWelcomeMessage(Profile profile){
        if(profile!=null){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Welcome " + profile.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        displayWelcomeMessage(profile);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        accessTokenTracker.stopTracking();
        profileTracker.stopTracking();
    }

    public void login() {
        initialize();
        if (!validate()) {
        }
        else {
            onLoginSuccess();
        }
    }

    public void onLoginSuccess() {

    }

    public boolean validate() {
        boolean valid = true;
        if (str_username.isEmpty()) {
            UsernameEt.setError("Please enter valid username.");
            valid = false;
        }
        if (str_password.isEmpty()) {
            PasswordEt.setError("Please enter valid password.");
            valid = false;
        }
        return valid;
    }

    public void initialize() {
        str_username = UsernameEt.getText().toString();
        str_password = PasswordEt.getText().toString();
        type = "login";
        BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(this);
        backgroundWorker.execute(type, str_username, str_password);
    }

    public void OpenReg(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, RegisterActivity.class));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize Twitter first, and then set the content view, like this:

```
Twitter.initialize(this);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
```

That's also the reason the button appears normally after you rotate the screen, because `onCreate()` gets called again.